# Use aggregations as filter ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, aggregation

ElasticSearch version 1.7.2

I am using aggregations as a product filter.

for instance, on the front end a user selects a product group and then the query will filter all the product for only the selecter product groups (groep in Dutch).

I also want to be able to search by text and match product groups. A product group my look like this:

> Componenten|Processoren|Intel| Socket 1155|S1155 - Core i3

I think I can't do this in 1 single field since it will either analyze the whole sentance, and therefor split the sentance, or it will use the full text alone.

So I made 2 fields saving the same information but using different index properties:

this is the mapping i am using in the index:

```
{


"settings":{
      "index":{
         "analysis":{
            "filter":{
               "synonym":{
                  "type":"synonym",
                  "synonyms_path":"synonyms.txt",
                  "stopwords":"_dutch_"
               }
            },
            "analyzer":{
               "synonym":{
                  "tokenizer":"standard",
                  "filter":[
                     "synonym",
                     "lowercase"
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{
      "products":{
         "properties":{
            "product_id":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "naam":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"analyzed",
               "analyzer":"synonym"
            },
            "merk":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed",
               "analyzer":"synonym"
            },
            "lijn":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed",
               "analyzer":"synonym"
            },
            "sku":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "omschrijving":{
               "type":"string",
               "boost":"0.5",
               "analyzer":"synonym"
            },
            "groep":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "groep_termen":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"analyzed"
            },
            "ean":{
               "type":"string",
               "boost":"2.0",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "kenmerken_json":{
               "type":"nested",
               "index":"analyzed",
               "dynamic":true
            },
            "kenmerken":{
               "type":"string",
               "analyzer":"synonym"
            },
            "levertijd":{
               "type":"integer"
            },
            "prijs":{
               "type":"integer"
            },
            "levertijd_min":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "levertijd_max":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "product_url":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "eol":{
               "type":"boolean"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

How can I both search on groep and aggregate and then filter on groep ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is multi field type.

[You can read about this here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/mapping-multi-field-type.html)

Later on you can query and aggregate the multi field as needed.